# Flutter Mapbox navigation crash

Tags: flutter, dictionary, navigation, crash, mapbox

I'm flutter dev and start working with mapbox, I already know how to build custom routes and show navigation messages. I build some routes and build logic how to switch. My problem is that after building the first route and starting navigation, some time after closing the first route I build another route and start navigating on it, just after that my app crashes and the app closes. Do you know what the problem is and how to solve it?

[image: Debug console messages]

Answer (score -1):

I have met this issue before.
I assume this error is relative to the Mapbox key.
Recommend checking the correct Mapbox key.